# Flask {{ STATIC_URL }} giving a 304 redirect when the static directory is unspecified

Tags: python, flask

Let's say I have a Flask application where

```python
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
```

That is, `{{ STATIC_URL }} == ""` (empty string) and the static files are not stored under a dedicated `/static` directory (e.g. `http://www.example.com/img/logo.png` instead of `http://www.example.com/static/img/logo.png`)

Is it ok if I just leave it this way? The GET requests to any URL that contains `{{ STATIC_URL }}` give a `304` redirect instead of a `200` status code if I leave the variable in my code.

Is it necessary to:

1. Delete all occurrences of `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in my templates?
2. Create a real static directory instead of just setting it equal to an empty string?
3. Leave all occurrences of `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in my templates so that I can set a new static directory in the future if necessary?

Comment: What is the reason to avoid creating the `static` directory?

Comment: @msvalkon No particular reason, I just never set one. I don't know if there's a best-practice that says you have to create a `static` directory. My app was migrated over from Django which is why the `{{ STATIC_URL }}` variables are still in the templates.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are porting over from Django and you want to do the minimum necessary to move.  So you updated Flask with a context variable named `STATIC_URL` and you set your static URL path to `''`.  This let you serve your static content from the root of your domain. Am I right?

Comment: @SeanVieira: Yes, that's correct. I don't mind doing more than the "minimum necessary", I'm wondering if there are any unintentional consequences to having a blank static URL.

Answer (score 15):

HTTP response 304 is for "Redirection to a previously cached result".

This means Flask is telling your browser that it already has the content.

Clear your Browser cache and you will notice that Flask returns a 200 on your next request.