# Render different Image on User selection Flask

Tags: python, opencv, flask, computer-vision

I am making a background removal flask web app, something like the virtual background that applies in Google meet, user could choose the background image based on their selection, however there is a problem that opencv only renders my initial image, when user made a selection of background image, opencv doesnt switch to that, I have tried printing the image path and its correct, i have looked into the terminal and it shows 304 error code, from what i know its a redirection to previously cached result from this post [304 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24667091/flask-static-url-giving-a-304-redirect-when-the-static-directory-is-unspec). I guess it just redirects to my initial image, I have used session.clear() but turns out it didnt work, below is my code for app.py and background_removal.py, also it shows "Not success" for background_removal.py everytime i switch to a different image, im not sure why:

app.py

```
def generate_background_frames(path_x, bg_image = ''):
    if bg_image == '':
        bg_image = 'autumn_leaves.jpg'
        yolo_output = bgremoval(path_x, bg_image)
    else:
        yolo_output = bgremoval(path_x, bg_image)

    for detection_ in yolo_output:
        ref,buffer=cv2.imencode('.jpg',detection_)
        frame=buffer.tobytes()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                    b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame +b'\r\n')

@app.route('/background_removal', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def background_removal():
    session.clear()
    form = UploadFileForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        file = form.file.data
        file.save(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               secure_filename(file.filename)))  # Then save the file
        session['video_path'] = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                                             secure_filename(file.filename))
    return render_template('background_removal.html', form=form)
    
@app.route('/bgremoval_video', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def bgremoval_video():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected_image = request.json.get('selectedImage') + '.jpg'
        return Response(generate_background_frames(path_x=session.get('video_path', None), bg_image=selected_image),mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
    return Response(generate_background_frames(path_x=session.get('video_path', None)),mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

@app.route('/bgremoval_webapp', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def bgremoval_webapp():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected_image = request.json.get('selectedImage') + '.jpg'
        return Response(generate_background_frames(path_x=0, bg_image=selected_image), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
    return Response(generate_background_frames(path_x=0), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

part of my code for background_removal.py

```
def bgremoval(path_x, img):
  video_capture = path_x

  BG_COLOR = (192, 192, 192)
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_capture)
  with mp_selfie_segmentation.SelfieSegmentation(
      model_selection=1) as selfie_segmentation:
    bg_image = cv2.imread('static/img/' + img)

    while cap.isOpened():
      success, image = cap.read()
      if not success:
        print("=======> Not success")
        break
```